# Can't install Pokemon Go after factory reset - android 4.4.2

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4 installed, and I had Pokemon Go installed on it from the app store. However, after performing a factory reset and trying to reinstall the app on the phone I am getting the "not compatible with your device" message on the Play store.

How can this be possible on a device that had no problem running the app prior to the factory reset?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out immediately. If someone else has this problem, the fix for me was to clear cache for google play services and google play store and reopen the app page.